How dense exactly is a vacuum in space (because of quantum fluctuations)?
You hear all the time that quantum fluctuations take up a given amount of energy in a vacuum, and this is how experiments such as The Casimir Effect gets the results that they do.
Have we actually calculated the typical energy level, above ground state, for a vacuum in a pocket of space? Is this a pointless question? Is it completely random, given the uncertainty principle? Is there an average energy level that could be calculated as a number? Furthermore, by our current understanding, is it clear that quantum fluctuations are the only thing that inhabits theoretical empty space? Is dark energy a massive factor?
It's worth noting that I realise the only thing physics can agree on with this phenomenon is that quantum fluctuations are convenient mathematically, although there does appear to be something real about them, which I know does not translate necessarily to physical particles.

There are no vacuum fluctuations. The Casimir effect is due to boundary conditions that violate the local symmetry of the vacuum. The question is not pointless at all, but the way it is being "explained" to the public is, at least in my opinion, not very satisfactory. Does "squeezing" of the vacuum result in "real particles"? Yes, it absolutely does. That is, in some way, what we are doing with accelerators.

Isn't this the most famous fail of QFT by like 80 orders of magnitude: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem (which is too big of a question for 1 PSE answer).
